# how to unittest payment gateway code

Tags: unit-testing

I was just curious as to strategies to unittest payment gateway integration code

Basically you hand off processing to a 3rd party website, who accepts the creditcard details, and then passes back a response.

Do i just setup mock responses to check that my code behaves as expected for the various responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should definitely mock-up the 3rd party response. With unit tests, you are only interested in the functionality of *your* code, not in the integration. The integration with the provider is checked in integration tests.

Comment: i think i asked the wrong question, do you have any pointers for automating integration tests

Answer (score 0):

Some merchants have a test credit card number you can put in.  I would contact them and ask about it.  It's different for each company.